# Overriding delegateEvents in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

One of my views should be listening for window resize events, so I'm trying to override delegateEvents and undelegateEvents to bind/unbind that listener.

In the view class, I've put this:

```
delegateEvents: => 
    $(window).on 'resize',@windowResized
    super

undelegateEvents: => 
    $(window).off 'resize',@windowResized
    super
```

But somehow, this results in undelegateEvents getting called by delegateEvents immediately once the view is instantiated, which I assume is its way of handling some error case.  Why wouldn't this work and what is the correct way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Edit:

It looks like the problem may not have to do with overriding delegateEvents after all.  Even with the custom delegateEvents method commented out, undelegateEvents gets called immediately.  Why could this be?

Edit 2:

To add even more weirdness to the mix, even after undelegateEvents gets called, the other events defined in the events property continue to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at Backbone source code, the `View.delegateEvents` method is defined as follows:

```
 delegateEvents: function(events) {
      if (!(events || (events = _.result(this, 'events')))) return;
      this.undelegateEvents();
      //...
 }
```

So Backbone internally calls `undelegateEvents` first thing. This is presumably to make the `delegateEvents` method re-entrant, so it can be called multiple times without side-effects.

You can work around this by letting the superclass delegate events first:

```
delegateEvents: => 
  super
  $(window).on 'resize',@windowResized
```